# Do expectation values over all possible states uniquely specify an operator?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, hilbert-space, operators

Suppose I have two operators $A$ and $B$ which each obey $\langle\psi|A|\psi\rangle = \langle\psi|B|\psi\rangle$ for all elements $|\psi\rangle$ of the space. Does this imply $A=B$? I remember seeing a proof on Stack Exchange way back when but can't seem to dig it up now.

That $\langle\psi_1|A|\psi_2\rangle = \langle\psi_1|B|\psi_2\rangle$ for all elements $|\psi_{1/2}\rangle$ is sufficient to conclude $A=B$ is clear from considering a particular basis as the $|\psi_{1}\rangle$, but obviously this is a stronger condition (at first glance) than the former.

Bonus points (generalizing from pure states): Does $\operatorname{trace}\{A \rho\} = \operatorname{trace}\{B\rho\}$ for all valid (density/state) operators $\rho$ ($\rho$ nonnegative, of unit trace, and self-adjoint) imply that $A=B$? Obviously answering this (in the affirmative) answers the first question, so please feel free to just answer this.

Edited to include an image describing the operator. Image included as I'm not sure how to describe the velocity opreator $\textbf{V}$ which Ballentine defines.
[image]

Comment: This question of mine and answers therein may help, I can't tell if the answer to this question is contained in the answers without thinking harder: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/726870/

Comment: Finite or infinite dimensions?

Comment: I proved this once in an exercise. I think this only works for hermitian operators. Having complex eigenvalues makes for too many degrees of freedom.

Comment: @NorbertSchuch This question came up in the context (Ballentine Chapter 3, equation 3.38) of connecting the symmetry generators on Hilbert space (from Galilean symmetries) to the underlying dynamical variables and so I think the author was suggesting it holds quite generally?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Proving polarization identity for operators in complex vector spaces](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/212069/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assume for simplicity that the operators $A,B$ are bounded so we don't run into any domain issues. Note that
$$\langle \psi\pm\phi,A(\psi\pm\phi)\rangle = \langle \psi,A\psi\rangle + \langle \phi,A\phi\rangle \pm \langle \psi,A\phi\rangle \pm \langle \phi,A\psi\rangle$$
$$\langle \psi\pm i\phi,A(\psi\pm i\phi)\rangle = \langle \psi,A\psi\rangle + \langle \phi,A\phi\rangle \pm i\langle \psi,A\phi\rangle \mp i \langle \phi,A\psi\rangle$$

A bit of algebra yields that

$$4\langle \psi,A\phi\rangle = \langle \psi+\phi,A(\psi+\phi)\rangle - \langle \psi-\phi,A(\psi-\phi)\rangle $$
$$-i \bigg[\langle \psi+i\phi,A(\psi+i\phi)\rangle -  \langle \psi-i\phi,A(\psi-i\phi)\rangle\bigg]$$
This is an example of a so-called *polarization identity*.  Your desired result follows straightforwardly from here.

> Bonus points (generalizing from pure states): Does $\operatorname{trace}\{A \rho\} = \operatorname{trace}\{B\rho\}$ for all valid (density/state) operators $\rho$ ($\rho$ nonnegative, of unit trace, and self-adjoint) imply that $A=B$?

Yes, but you have it backwards - this is a *weaker* statement than the first one. If $\mathrm{Tr}(A\rho)= \mathrm{Tr}(B\rho)$ for all density operators $\rho$, than in particular it holds for all pure states $\rho= |\psi\rangle\langle \psi|$, at which point the argument above takes over.  In other words, we don't need to assume the equality holds for *all* density operators - the set of *pure* density operators suffices.

Comment: Re: the first part of your answer -- thank you! Obviously that identity establishes the "stronger" condition I mentioned in the problem (I say this to convince myself of that fact). Re: the second part -- thank you as well!

Comment: Incidentally, I perhaps should have waited with a more general question. The operator in question here (one of them, at least) is the position $X$ operator on Hilbert space. I don't believe it's bounded alhtough I'm not sure it materially changes things (I'm sure there are ways to phrase things in terms of rigged Hilbert spaces?).

Comment: @EE18 The position operator is not bounded on $L^2(\mathbb R)$. What is the other operator you're considering?

Comment: Please see the attached image -- I wasn't sure how else to convey meaning.

Comment: @EE18 I see. Note that the text is actually just seeking *some* $\mathbf V$ which has the desired property, and clearly $i[H,\mathbf Q]$ fits the bill.  At the physicists level of rigor, this is sufficient to motivate the definition [...]

Comment: [...] but mathematically, one might want to check whether $\mathbf V$ is (essentially) self-adjoint and then attempt to classify its self-adjoint extensions. I am not sure, but my suspicion is that $\mathbf V$ is essentially self-adjoint on the set of smooth, compactly-supported functions and so for all practical purposes you can think of (the closure of) $\mathbf V$ as the unique self-adjoint operator which satisfies your requirements.

Comment: See [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/212069/proving-polarization-identity-for-operators-in-complex-vector-spaces) for the case of infinite-dimensions and operators defined only on a dense subspace.